# Why cannot get list of files in my directory?

Tags: android, android-file

I am working with Android new project.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (isExternalStorageReadable()) {
            File meetings = getDocumentsStorageDir("Meetings");

            if (meetings != null && meetings.exists()) {
                if (meetings.isDirectory()) {
                    String[] list = meetings.list();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }

    public File getDocumentsStorageDir(String albumName) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), albumName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Directory not created");
        }

        return file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

My `meetings` object is not `null` and `exists` and `isDirectory`. But I cannot get the list of files in side this directory.

My `list` object is null

I have set the following permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Perhaps [you have the `<uses-permission>` in the wrong place, or have not implemented runtime permissions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare runtime permissions, i forgot about them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher, you need to [handle runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for `dangerous` permissions like `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Merely having the `<uses-permission>` element is insufficient.